# EXCEL rounding big numbers

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Recently i have discovered that excel is rounding numbers that are bigger than 15 digits. This is a great disappointing situation for me. While I can figure out to correct this problem, I need to know one thing. Does excel round up all digits in same column even if it is not more than 15 digits considering the column has various length of digits from 1 to 17? Or does it only round the digits that it finds only above 15 digits in  that very column?

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the 15 digit limit by placing an apostrophe *(single quote)* at the beginning of the number when you are typing it in.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. But does auto truncation only effect the number that is above 15 digits or does it effect all the number in that column considering the column has all length of number from digit 1 - 17?

Comment: *Numerical values* are limited to 15 digits.

Comment: thanks. But my question is whether the truncation effects all the cells irrespective of length in a column, if that very column has even one number that is more than 15 digits?

Comment: The truncation effects any cell with more than 15 digits_______it is not genuine truncation: the extra digits are replaced with **0's**